# Wpf templating with TabControl

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following xaml.
Maturities is an array of integer [2012;2013;2014 etc...]

I would like to replace GetHisto2013 with Gethisto(currentitem) ....

-> Can I parameterize the ItemsSource of the Datagrid with the current Item of the Tabcontrol?

-> How can I call a function of my view model with such a parameter from XAML ?

```
   <TabControl ItemsSource="{StaticResource maturities}">
       <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
          </DataTemplate>
       </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
       <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <ContentControl>
                <DataGrid x:Name="quotes13"  AutoGenerateColumns="True"  ItemsSource="{StaticResource GetHisto2013}" />
             </ContentControl>
          </DataTemplate>
       </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

Comment: When you want to call that function in ViewModel?

Comment: whenever GetHisto2013 is currently called

Comment: And when GetHisto2013 is called?

Comment: i might be missing something in your question. it is called whenever 'quotes13' is rendered, but that is obvious, so I dont see what you mean.